# How to disable the loop in a <video>

Tags: html, html5-video

How to disable the loop in this video? I have try use the property loop="false" but don't work. Thanks.

http://codepen.io/FelipeMartinin/pen/cwxmi

Answer (score 0):

Just remove loop="false" from your code, it is working fine..Pls check **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JHakA**  and  to add loop to a video this is the way `<video controls loop></video>`

Comment: Hey man, how are you? Thanks for the answer. But, after the video end, appears a black screen. How to freeze in the last frame from the video?